# migration file showing database name in typeorm migration file

Tags: nodes, typeorm

i am generating migration using typeorm and the output file is showing database name

```
import {MigrationInterface, QueryRunner} from "typeorm";

export class PostRefactoring1632822259113 implements MigrationInterface {
    name = 'PostRefactoring1632822259113'

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE \`dev_dbname\`.\`loan_process_trackers\` (\`id\` char(36) NOT NULL, \`fund_type\` enum ('BRIDGE_LOAN', 'VENTURE_DEBT') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'BRIDGE_LOAN', \`next_process_stage\` enum ('REQUEST_RAISED', 'DOCUMENTS_SUBMITTED', 'DOCUMENTS_VERIFIED', 'LOAN_APPROVED', 'LOAN_PROCESSED') NOT NULL, \`documents_request_raised\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, \`documents_submitted\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, \`documents_verified\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, \`loan_approved\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, \`loan_processed\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, \`created_at\` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6), \`updated_at\` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6), \`startup_id\` char(36) NULL, UNIQUE INDEX \`REL_33d6136fd8b0eb52e6f82d5f39\` (\`startup_id\`), PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)) ENGINE=InnoDB`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`dev_dbname\`.\`loan_process_trackers\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`FK_33d6136fd8b0eb52e6f82d5f399\` FOREIGN KEY (\`startup_id\`) REFERENCES \`dev_8vdx\`.\`startups\`(\`id\`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`dev_dbname\`.\`loan_process_trackers\` DROP FOREIGN KEY \`FK_33d6136fd8b0eb52e6f82d5f399\``);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP INDEX \`REL_33d6136fd8b0eb52e6f82d5f39\` ON \`dev_dbname\`.\`loan_process_trackers\``);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE \`dev_dbname\`.\`loan_process_trackers\``);
    }

}
```

and i want to use this migration in other env as well but because of the database name i am not able to sync

Answer (score 0):

I had such issue and solved it by getting current database name.

```
const { database } = (await queryRunner.query(`SELECT DATABASE() as \`database\``))[0];
```

Then you can use it in your code as usual.